# How to visualise 3D vector rotation around a line?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If we want to rotate a 2D vector we need only angle $\theta$ by which we want to rotate the vector. And we have only two possibilities: one for clockwise rotation and other for counterclockwise rotation. Pretty simple!

But things get complicated when we want to rotate 3D vectors. Mere giving an angle is **not** sufficient as we would have infinite possibilities for rotated vector. In fact, it is not hard to see that all possibilities of rotated vectors would make a cone, right?

So in 3D rotations we rotate a vector around a **line**, right?

But my problem is that I am not able to **visualise** how we are rotating a vector around a line. I don't need any rotation matrix or any other algebraic stuff. I just want to visualise the rotation through 3D diagrams.

It would be a great help if you spare some time to answer this question in detail.

You might simply take a 3D vector as an example, and show how we are getting a rotated vector around a line, for example z-axis.

Thank you.

Comment: We rotate about an axis and we usually specify the axis with a vector. As in the 2D case, we can have clockwise or counter-clockwise rotations. If one vector is rotated about another, we can imagine the tip of the rotated vector tracing out an arc on a cone.

Comment: If an intersecting line with an axis rotates, it generates  a cone. When line is skew, it generates a hyperboloid of revolution of one sheet.

Answer (score 1):

tl; dr:

[image: Rotating vectors in three-space around a line]

---

In Euclidean geometry, two planes are *orthogonal* if every vector of one plane is orthogonal to every vector in the other. In four-space, for example, the planes $\{(u, v, 0, 0) : \text{$u$, $v$ real}\}$ and $\{(0, 0, x, y) : \text{$x$, $y$ real}\}$ are orthogonal.

In Euclidean $n$-space, a *rotation* acts on some collection of mutually-orthogonal planes and fixes whatever space is orthogonal to the direct sum. This gives Euclidean rotations in odd-dimensional spaces a slightly different character than rotations in even-dimensional spaces: Every rotation of an odd-dimensional space has at least one line that is fixed, but there exist rotations of even-dimensional spaces that fix only one point (the *center* of rotation).

In three-space there do not exist two orthogonal planes; a rotation acts on some plane (here the plane containing the tail of the red arrow) and fixes the orthogonal line, the *axis* (the line containing the black arrow).

Comment: I so badly want to understand how to use Epix but I can't seem to crack into the text pdf of it. Pensive

Comment: @Aplateofmomos Do you mean the manual is hard to read, that the sample files are hard to use, something else...?

Comment: The manual is hard to read but it may be that I don't have experience reading such manuals

Comment: @Aplateofmomos Looking at and experimenting with the sample files is probably an easier way to get started. Have you got the software installed and running?